# How to check a PropertyKey already existed in Titan database

Tags: graph-databases, titan

```
 /**
     * Returns the property key with the given name. If automatic type making is enabled, it will make the property key
     * using the configured default type maker if a key with the given name does not exist.
     *
     * @param name name of the property key to return
     * @return the property key with the given name
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if a property key with the given name does not exist or if the
     *                                  type with the given name is not a property key
     * @see PropertyKey
     */
    public PropertyKey getPropertyKey(String name);
```

getPropertyKey  method will always return a prpertyKey.

Answer (score 0):

To check for if a key exists in the database use:

```
mgmt.containsRelationType(keyToCheck)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of the latest version of Titan (1.0.0) you can use `com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanTransaction` to check if property key exists in Titan DB schema. http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/1.0.0/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanTransaction.html

Example:

```
TitanTransaction tt = TitanGraph.newTransaction();
boolean exists = tt.containsPropertyKey("keyName");
```